# How to get minimum date by group id per client id

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to Select Group ID, and minimum dates per clients ID.

This is sample data set.

```
ClientID    GroupID DataDate        
1           9       2016-05-01      
2           8       2015-04-01
3           7       2016-07-05      
1           6       2015-01-05      
1           5       2014-11-12      
2           4       2016-11-02      
1           3       2013-02-14      
2           2       2011-04-01
```

I wrote

```
SELECT 
    clientID, MIN(DataDate)  
FROM sampleTable  
GROUP BY clientID
```

But in this query, I do not have `GroupID` selected. I need to include `GroupID` to join another table.

If I do:

```
Select 
    ClientID, GroupID, MIN(DataDate)  
FROM sampleTable  
GROUP BY ClientID, GroupID
```

It won't really get minimum dates per client.

Could you help me. How I should do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead:

```
SELECT
    ClientID, GroupID, DataDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY DataDate)
    FROM SampleData
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you want to include ties, use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I am trying to Join multiple table later. I don't know if I can use Order by in subquery.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` here is used by the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, it's allowable. You could easily `JOIN` tables to `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your question correctly .
You want to display min dates for each client id's

If my table has data like this:

```
    CID GID D1
    1   9   03-06-2016
    1   6   01-06-2017
    1   5   01-06-2015
    1   3   01-06-2014
    2   4   01-06-2017
    2   8   01-06-2014
    3   5   03-06-2016
    2   4   01-06-2011
```

Output :

```
    CID GID D1
    1   3   01-06-2014
    2   4   01-06-2011
    3   5   03-06-2016
```

This is what i think you can go with .

```
select cx.cid,cx.gid, cx.d1 from cli cx  where cx.d1=(select min(c1.d1) from cli c1 where c1.cid=cx.cid)
group by cx.cid,cx.gid,cx.d1
order by cx.gid
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see.. You are trying to get minimum date and match with outer cx table.   But What if gid have more than one same date.?